# Calling Python Flask (factory approach) with Gunicorn

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask app (main.py) written using factory approach ,

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request
import logging
import json


class EndpointAction(object):

    def __init__(self, action):
        self.action = action
        self.response = Response(status=200, headers={})

    def __call__(self, *args):
        response = self.action()
        if response is not None:
            return response
        else:
            return self.response


class FlaskAppWrapper(object):
    app = None

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.app = Flask(name)

    def run(self):
        self.app.run()

    def add_endpoint(self, endpoint=None, endpoint_name=None, handler=None, t_methods=None):
        self.app.add_url_rule(endpoint, endpoint_name, EndpointAction(handler), methods=t_methods)


def action():
    action.data = request.get_json()
    return "OK"



def returning_action():
    return render_template('index.html')


a = FlaskAppWrapper('wrap')
a.add_endpoint(endpoint='/data', endpoint_name='data', handler=action, t_methods=["POST"])


# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     a.run()
```

I have a wsgi.py file in the same directory like -

```
from main import a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a.run()
```

I am trying to run my flask app (structured using factory approach) using gunicorn with

```
gunicorn -w 4 wsgi:app
```

since a or app is starting from wsgi.py

and I run into this error : gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>

how do i start my main.py using gunicorn in my local server ?

Comment: You're trying to load `wsgi:app`, but your `wsgi.py` file doesn't have an `app` variable. You've named it `a`.

Comment: yes , that's because i have used a as Flask app instance in main.py

Comment: I was trying to point at a discrepancy between the name you're asking for on the command line (`app`) and the name you're using in your script (`a`). Fix the discrepancy and things should work.

Comment: you mean change to gunicorn -w 4 wsgi:a ?

Comment: Still doesn't work!